# Using jQuery in Google Maps infowindow

Tags: jquery, infowindow, fcbkcomplete

I want to use the `fcbk_autocomplete` function I downloaded from http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html in Google Maps `infowindow`.

Originally I have set the content of `infowindow` as shown below

```
var friends = document.getElementsByTagName('option'), 
    res = '';

for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
    res = res + '<option value="'+friends[i].id+'">' + friends[i].value + '</option>';
}

var contentString = '<form method="post" action="mapit.do">' 
    + '<textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="5">Enter your gossips here...</textarea><br>'
    + 'image url: <input type="text" cols="40" name="url"></input><br>'
    + '<input type="hidden" name="position" value="' + event.latLng.toUrlValue() + '"/>'
    + '<select id="select3" name="about">' + res + '</select>'
    + '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />'
    + '</form>';
```

`options` is a list of data I want to select from and they are stored in an invisible division.

After I open the infowindow, I tried to call the `fcbkcomplete` function by:

```
$("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
    addontab: true,                   
    maxitems: 10,
    input_min_size: 0,
    height: 10,
    cache: true,
    newel: true,
});
```

But it has no effect on the `select3` section. I tried to call `document.getElementById("select3")` and it gives me null. My question is where can I call this function to make sure it sees the element with id select3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to emulate without google maps loaded and everything, but I started a [jsFiddle for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/NwD8W/).

The plugin you're attempting to use appears to be working in my context; however, that may not explain the behavior you've witnessed with attempting to use it within a `gmap info window`.  Nevertheless, if you want you can add your `gmap` stuff to the javascript source and I can help you debug from there.

Comment: Thank you so much It worked!! I added that div to my view and then I used   var layer = document.getElementById("mock-infowindow");

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: layer
   });
to make it work